# get data by id in grid view

Tags: asp.net

I have a table with threads for a forum, the thread name is a link and once clicked it passes the thread_id to the comments page, I need to know how to then display all the comments with the thread_id that is passed?

Have tried:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CommentsDataSource" runat="server"
SelectCommand="select * from comments where thread_id=@thread_id" >
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="@thread_id" QueryStringField="thread_id" Runat="Server" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="comment" HeaderText="Comment" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

but it doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a parameter in your datasource that reads from the QueryString.  For example, here is a `SqlDataSource` which uses `thread_id` querystring parameter (assuming your link navigates to something like `Comments.aspx?thread_id=123`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CommentsDataSource" runat="server"
    SelectCommand="select * from comments where thread_id=@thread_id" ...>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="@thread_id" QueryStringField="thread_id" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="CommentsGrid" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="CommentsDataSource" ...
```

Comment: I get this error:
unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryStringParameter' to type 'System.Web.UIControl'.

Comment: Have you researched into how `SqlDataSource`, `SelectParameters`, and `QueryStringParameter` work?  Google them to get a rough idea.  Don't just drop my example code into your application and expect it to  work without understanding the purpose behind it and how to integrate into your particular business case.  Can you update your question post to show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Updated! I will Google them and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Ah. You have a couple of typos (one was my fault).  Don't close the tag `<asp:SqlDataSource ... />`, otherwise it ignores the contents (remove the `/` before `>`).  Also, the closing tag should be `</asp:SqlDataSource>` not `</asp>`, I fixed after you tried the code.

Comment: Also I am using web services to provide access to the database and I am under strict instructions that all access to the database must be via this web service.

Comment: Right. In that case you might use an `ObjectDataSource` or `LinqDataSource` to wire up to your custom business logic.  However, the concept can be the same with QueryStringParameter in either case to pass in a parameter that you can use in the method.  If you need to read the querystring parameter directly, it is possible with `Request.QueryString["thread_id"]` inside your code logic to pass it as a parameter to a web service, for instance.